# Error message "ENOENT, no such file or directory"

Tags: node.js, express

I'm getting this error from my Node.js application:

> ENOENT, no such file or directory '~/Desktop/MyApp/newversion/partials/navigation.jade'

I know the file is there because when I try to open the file using the exact copied and pasted path, it works. I also know the application is using the right directory because, well, it outputs it in the error.

Comment: Delete package-lock.json and run `npm install` again

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Tilde expansion is a shell thing. Write the proper pathname (probably `/home/`yourusername`/Desktop/etcetcetc`) or use
`process.env.HOME + '/Desktop/blahblahblah'`

Comment: Hmm, I thought that was handled by 
`app.locals.basedir = '~/Desktop/BitBox/thenewbox';`

I tried 

`app.set('home', process.env.HOME || '/Users/Kinnard/Desktop/BitBox/thenewbox');`

But that didn't work, same error.

Comment: Ok, just changing `app.locals.basedir = '~/Desktop/BitBox/thenewbox';` to the absolute path worked. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having this error too. I have no path: ..node_module/rxjs. What am i doing wrong? my issue: ** ./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/index.js Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '..\ClientApp\node_modules\rxjs_esm5\index.js'**

Comment: You might want to look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637099/app-base-path-from-a-module-in-nodejs

Answer (score 50):

I believe [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20753566/4575793) is the correct answer to this problem but I was getting this error when I tried installing my npm package with `npm install mailgun-js` (see below):

[image: Output for npm install mailgun-js]

The fix for me was: **`npm init --yes`**

[image: Output for the previous command npm init --yes, then checking with npm install mailgun-js]

Comment: Can you explain what this does and why it might fix the issue?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37645798/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21):

I was also plagued by this error, and after trying all the other answers, magically found the following solution:

Delete file *package-lock.json* and the [node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) folder, and then run `npm install` again.

If that doesn't work, try running these in order:

```
npm install
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g npm
npm install
```

(taken from [@Thisuri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52566618/4575793) and [@Mathias Falci's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753550/error-message-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory/59286978#comment97262069_20753550) respectively)

And then re-deleting the above files and rerunning `npm install`.

It worked for me!

Comment: After deleting node_modules :
command not found: npm

Answer (score 20):

1. First try `npm install`. If the issue is not yet fixed, try the following one after the other.
2. `npm cache clean`, then
3. `npm install -g npm` , then
   `npm install`. Finally
4. `ng serve --o` to run the project.

Comment: what does npm install -g npm do? any doc i can find info about it?

Comment: @Prusio It is the command to update npm (after it has been installed).

Answer (score 10):

```
__dirname
```

Gives you the current Node.js application's root directory.

In your case, you'd use

```
__dirname + '/Desktop/MyApp/newversion/partials/navigation.jade';
```

See this answer:

*[How can I get the application base path from a module in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637099/app-base-path-from-a-module-in-nodejs)*

Answer (score 4):

I had that issue using the *path* module:

```
const path = require('path');
```

And also do not forget to create the uploads directory first period.

Comment: What do you mean by *"create the uploads directory first period"*?

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: This *seems* like a completely bogus answer.

Answer (score 2):

For those running [Laravel Mix](https://laravel-mix.com/) with `npm run watch`, just terminate the script and run the command again.

Comment: How is that related to the question? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52585763/edit), not here in comments (*********** ***without*** *********** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 2):

Specifically, `rm yarn.lock` and then `yarn install` fixed this for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the trouble was caused by the fact that my code folder was a subdirectory of my [Dropbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox_%28service%29) folder, on Windows 10. During the build process, the Dropbox application would complain about working with more than 500,000 files.

I moved my folder out from the Dropbox directory and now it builds fine!

Answer (score 1):

When this happened to me, it was when trying to run [Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/latest/index.html) tests in an Angular project.  The `tsconfig.spec.js` file turned out to be incorrect.  It was basically pointing to the wrong directory, and so the error was simply trying to tell me this.

[image]

For example, we had `../tsconfig.json` instead of `./tsconfig.json`, so the runner was looking for tests in the wrong folder.  This may be a different use case from the OP, but the same error message brought me here and led me down the rabbit hole of trying the `npm install` solutions to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

It usually occurs due to a mismatch in the `npm` version used while creating the `package-lock.json` that currently exist and the one you are using now.

Removing the *package-lock.json* and running `npm install` worked for me.

Comment: forgot about this one! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that you are missing an `.npmrc` file if you are pulling any packages that are not publicly available.

You will need to add an `.npmrc` file at the root directory and add the private/internal registry inside of the `.npmrc` file like this:

```
registry=http://private.package.source/secret/npm-packages/
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:** I have the same issue, where a few guys work on one project and change package dependencies.

**Solution:** Just kill file `package-lock.json` and run `npm i` again

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was running the terminal in the wrong folder. Please make sure that you navigate to the folder containing your code (App.js and others) and then use a command prompt (for Windows) to open the code. I am using [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code), so it is to type "code." after I have opened the command prompt in the exact folder where my code is in.

Comment: Re "`code.`": Do you mean "`code`" or "`code .`"?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you are just not in the right directory. Check that once and try "npm start" again.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this upgrading a Phoenix app to 1.6, which does not use Node.js, so in fact it is not needed. However, `elixir_buildpack.config` had a reference to `phoenix_static_buildpack.config`, which defined node. Remove the reference, and the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I didn't have a *package.json* file in my working directory.