# How can I get the application base path from a module in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, module, path, node.js-fs

I'm building a web application in Node.js, and I'm implementing my API routes in separate modules. In one of my routes I'm doing some file manipulation and I need to know the base app path. If I use `__dirname`, it gives me the directory that houses my module of course.

I'm currently using this to get the base application path (given that I know the relative path to the module from base path):

```
path.join(__dirname, "../../", myfilename)
```

Is there a better way than using `../../`? I'm running Node.js under Windows, so there isn't any `process.env.PWD`, and I don't want to be platform-specific anyway.

Comment: Using the line above multiple times/in multiple modules is repetitive and inconsistent. It might be useful to create a _static_ function in a _static_ class (for example `Paths.getBasePath();`) in that case.
You'll only need to update the relative path in the function mentioned above when your project structure changes. With an approach like this, you can use `require('./Paths').getBasePath();` anywhere, without the need to use `../../` again.

Comment: this is very cheeky but it is working.. I am going to use this, only one reliable so far for my internal modules

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The approach of using [`__dirname`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) is the most reliable one. It will always give you correct directory. You do not have to worry about `../../` in Windows environment as [`path.join()`](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path1_path2) will take care of that.

There is an alternative solution though. You can use [`process.cwd()`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd) which returns the [current working directory](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Working-Directory.html) of the process. That command works fine if you execute your Node.js application from the base application directory. However, if you execute your Node.js application from different directory, say, its parent directory (e.g., `node yourapp\index.js)` then the `__dirname` mechanism will work much better.

Comment: `process.cwd()` works great with the app running at the app base path. Thanks! The `../../` works, but it feels more hacked together.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [path.resolve()](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths) without arguments to get the working directory which is usually the base application path. If the argument is a relative path then it's assumed to be relative to the [current working directory](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Working-Directory.html), so you can write

```
require(path.resolve(myfilename));
```

to require your module at the application root.

Answer (score 10):

You can define a global variable like in your *app.js* file:

```
global.__basedir = __dirname;
```

Then you can use this global variable anywhere. Like this:

```
var base_path = __basedir
```

Comment: What I don't like about this one is that I lose autocompletion :(

Comment: I see people don't recommend to use global variables generally.

Comment: In that case, create a new file in the root of your project called "basePath.ts" and then `export const basePath = __dirname;` from it. Then you can import {basePath} wherever you need to and use that. And you'll have autocomplete.