# NPM Install ENOENT no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, npm-install, node-modules

I'm getting this error when running `npm install --save-dev gulp-coffee`

> ENOENT: No such file or directory

[image]

I have a package.json file in my root directory though

[image]

Didn't have any issues yesterday installing node modules but today I can't install dependencies

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/20753550/1740715

Comment: I tried these as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484829/npm-cant-find-package-json , but I still cannot resolve the issue. I will just to just reclone my repo and reinstall nodejs, then my packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing seemed to work from other similar problems on stackoverflow, I ended up just deleting my repo. Then:

1. `git clone [my github url repo]`
2. `cd [folder with node dependencies]`
3. `npm install`  (installs node packages based on root package.json file)
4. Run my gulp commands to test `gulp watch`, modified files being watched to see if gulp was working as intended. *check to see files being changed as intended via git diff*

Worked fine for me, it doesn't solve the original problem. Not sure why my package.json files were missing or why I could not repopulate them with a `npm init`