# npm cordova error prevent install

Tags: cordova, npm

I cannot run any `npm install` commands due to an error that is popping up.  I am not sure what it means:

```
npm ERR! path /Users/.../Projects/.../file:cordova-dist/tools/cordova-common-1.5.1.tgz
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall stat
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/.../Projects/.../file:cordova-dist/tools/cordova-common-1.5.1.tgz'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

**What am I supposed to do to remedy the error?**

---

**Full Trace:**

This is the verbose trace stored in the .log folder for npm

```
16 silly install generateActionsToTake
17 silly diffTrees action count 5
18 silly diffTrees update cordova-common@file:file:cordova-dist/tools/cordova-common-1.5.1.tgz
19 silly diffTrees remove angular2-google-maps@0.17.0
20 silly diffTrees remove cordova 2
21 silly diffTrees remove node-sass 2
22 silly diffTrees remove npm-debug.log
23 silly decomposeActions action count 18
24 silly decomposeActions unbuild cordova-common@1.5.1
25 silly decomposeActions remove cordova-common@1.5.1
26 silly decomposeActions fetch cordova-common@file:file:cordova-dist/tools/cordova-common-1.5.1.tgz
27 silly decomposeActions extract cordova-common@file:file:cordova-dist/tools/cordova-common-1.5.1.tgz
28 silly decomposeActions preinstall cordova-common@file:file:cordova-dist/tools/cordova-common-1.5.1.tgz
29 silly decomposeActions build cordova-common@file:file:cordova-dist/tools/cordova-common-1.5.1.tgz
30 silly decomposeActions install cordova-common@file:file:cordova-dist/tools/cordova-common-1.5.1.tgz
31 silly decomposeActions postinstall cordova-common@file:file:cordova-dist/tools/cordova-common-1.5.1.tgz
32 silly decomposeActions finalize cordova-common@file:file:cordova-dist/tools/cordova-common-1.5.1.tgz
33 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json cordova-common@file:file:cordova-dist/tools/cordova-common-1.5.1.tgz
34 silly decomposeActions unbuild angular2-google-maps@0.17.0
35 silly decomposeActions remove angular2-google-maps@0.17.0
36 silly decomposeActions unbuild cordova 2
37 silly decomposeActions remove cordova 2
38 silly decomposeActions unbuild node-sass 2
39 silly decomposeActions remove node-sass 2
40 silly decomposeActions unbuild npm-debug.log
41 silly decomposeActions remove npm-debug.log
42 silly install executeActions
43 silly doSerial global-install 18
44 verbose correctMkdir /Users/.../.npm/_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
45 verbose lock using /Users/.../.npm/_locks/staging-e07da16c2da6e71c.lock for /Users/.../Documents/Projects/.../node_modules/.staging
46 silly doParallel extract 18
47 silly extract cordova-common@file:file:cordova-dist/tools/cordova-common-1.5.1.tgz
48 silly pacote trying cordova-common@file:file:cordova-dist/tools/cordova-common-1.5.1.tgz by hash: sha1-Z3DeDWIArW+Uoavok5tb2ezhOeM=
49 silly pacote data for sha1-Z3DeDWIArW+Uoavok5tb2ezhOeM= not present. Using manifest.
50 verbose unlock done using /Users/.../.npm/_locks/staging-e07da16c2da6e71c.lock for /Users/jeremylopez/Documents/Projects/.../node_modules/.staging
51 warn @ionic-native/file-opener@4.3.2 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
52 warn ajv-keywords@2.1.0 requires a peer of ajv@>=5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
53 warn ng2-charts@1.5.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
54 warn ng2-charts@1.5.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
55 warn The package @types/node is included as both a dev and production dependency.
56 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/.../Documents/Projects/.../file:cordova-dist/tools/cordova-common-1.5.1.tgz'
```

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753550/enoent-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: still get the same error.  the path shown is my projects root folder which has no packages directly inside.  Idk why it would be looking there for something

Comment: Looks like old Cordova version to me. I see cordova 2, while cordova 7 is the newest. Maybe reinstall cordova global again: install -g cordova
And make sure there is no cordova in your package.json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After locating the file causing the issue, `cordova-common`.  I was able to remove the android platform causing the issue (since I don't need it) and was able to re-run `npm install` without a failure.