# Azure DevOps Pipeline error when running docker-compose up

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an image that runs the Postman Newman tests collection with an HTML reporter. There is also a pipeline created in Azure DevOps.

Everything used to work fine, but recently the pipeline stopped running docker-compose up, although no changes have been made. Locally, everything continues to work.

Here is my Docker file:

```docker
FROM postman/newman:alpine

RUN npm install -g newman-reporter-htmlextra
RUN apk add --update gettext
RUN apk add --update jq

WORKDIR /etc/newman
COPY path/run.sh .
RUN chmod +x run.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "path/run.sh" ]
```

Pipeline crashes with the following message:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'path/run.sh'

Still, the strangest thing for me is that everything used to work, but no changes were made to these files, and now I get an error.
Maybe something was updated in Azure itself, but I didn't find any information about it?

- My *.sh file ending with **LF**

Comment: Check this if works: [ENOENT, no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753550/enoent-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the Azure Pipelines YAML file.
I also have a **docker-compose.override.yml** and adding the **additionalDockerComposeFiles** parameter with the path to that file solved the problem.

The fact that everything worked before, I think is related to changes in Azure DevOps, although I did not find any detailed information about this.